# WP_Query - Object manipulation vs WordPress functions

Tags: wp-query

Although this could be opinion based, there must be a some consistent way / optimised way of manipulating data from a `WP_Query`. For example, the 'best' way to get a posts title?

```
$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($query->have_posts()) {
     while ($query->have_posts()) {
         $query->the_post();

         $choice1 = get_the_title();
         $choice2 = the_title();
         $choice3 = $query->post->post_title;
     }
 }
```

I'm thinking due to consistency and reduction of function calls, the 3rd option may be a better choice (and a little more consistent since both the `if` and `while` statements use the object notation.)

The third option also gives much greater access to data over the limited number of WordPress functions. Are there any real drawbacks to using it? If not, why bother with the WordPress functions? Sanitation? Error catching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All 3 of these *could* do the same thing, it's just a matter of how you want to use them.

`the_title()` calls `get_the_title()` which gets the title by `$post->post_title`.

[View `the_title()` Source on Trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L43)

[View `get_the_title()` Source on Trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L111)

Personally, I would never use choice 3 as from a readability stand point it's not the most obvious what it's doing. On top of that as Milo points out, you do lose `the_title` filter which is found in `get_the_title()`:

`return apply_filters( 'the_title', $title, $id );`

Choice 1 / 2 are used in different scenarios. You can never assign `the_title()` ( without any parameters ) to a variable because by default it will echo out the title to the screen. The function `get_the_title()` is used to actually assign the title to a variable should you need to run any kind of manipulation on the post title.

You could use any of the choices to achieve the same result it just depends what you're trying to do.

Comment: All good answers, chose this because the Source helped me visualise how WP works a little better.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with accessing post content directly is that you lose the filters. Whether that matters depends on the context. If you're building a theme for distribution, you always want to use the API over directly accessing objects.

Answer (score 2):

As you might or might not know, the main query uses `WP_Query`, the only difference from a custom query as in your question is that the main query parses the URL to get the paramaters and arguments passed where a custom query uses user defined parameters and arguments.

The main query and any new instance of `WP_Query` returns exactly the same array of results and most important the same `WP_Post` objects for the posts returned in the `$posts` array

So, on performance, they are all the same. Any instance of `WP_Query` uses complex filters and caches to make them as performant as possible.

As already pointed out, make use of the template tags as the post objects (which is unfiltered) are run through filters before either being returned (`get_` prefix) or echoed (without the `get_` prefix).